# Capacitor Share is throwing an error - /data/data/${applicationId}/files/Filename.pdf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, plugins, capacitor

im using capacitor share for sharing pdf via email below is the code snippet

```
let directory = the.file.cacheDirectory;
this.file
.checkFile(directory, this.pdfconfig.fileName)
.then((res) => {
this.file
.writeFile(directory, this.pdfconfig.fileName, buffer, options)
.then((res) => {
    Share.canShare().then(async (value) => {
    await Share.share({
    title: title,
    text: body,
    url: res.nativeURL,
    dialogTitle: '',
    }).catch((e) => {
    console.log(e);
});
});
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        throw new Error(error);
    });
})
```

this code is perfectly working on ios
for android the share result is returning an error when i use the.file.dataDirectory and works fine for cacheDirectory

`Error: Failed to find configured root that contains /data/data/${applicationId}/files/filename.pdf at returnResult (VM4:744:32) at win.androidBridge.onmessage (VM4:719:21)`

in files_path.xml i have configured the path as this

```
`<external-files-path name="data/data/${applicationId}/files" path="."
/>`
```

Im pretty sure im making a mistake in path configuration
Please let me know where i am making the mistake